# JavaFX и многопоточность, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx, интерфейс

Есть два класса:
1. Класс, объект которого принимает элемент интерфейса (JavaFX) Label (метка) и выводит на неё (метку) постоянно обновляющуюся информацию:

```
package simpleclasstest;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;

/**
 *
 * @author Den
 */
public class SimpleClassTest {

    /**
     * Метка
     */
    Label lbl;

    /**
     * Количество циклов
     */
    int loops;

    /**
     * Конструктор
     * @param loops количество циклов
     */
    public SimpleClassTest(int loops) {
        this.loops = loops;
    }

    /**
     * Получение метки для выведения информации
     * @param lbl метка
     */
    public void setLbl(Label lbl) {
        this.lbl = lbl;
    }

    public void process(){
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            //собственно выведение информации на метку.
            lbl.setText("number - "+i);
            System.out.println("number - "+i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println("InterruptedException");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2.Класс-интерфейс (находится в другом пакете), содержит кнопку запускающую процесс в первом классе и метку(Label), которую также передаёт в объект первого класса (SimpleClassTest) и на которую тот выводит обновляющуюся информацию.

```
package fxclasstest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import simpleclasstest.SimpleClassTest;

public class FXClassTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox();

        /**
         * Метка на которую должна выводиться обновляющаяся информация.
         */
        Label lbl = new Label("Test");
        Button btn = new Button("Start");


        SimpleClassTest sct = new SimpleClassTest(25);
        //передаём метку классу который выводит на неё информацию.
        sct.setLbl(lbl);

        btn.setOnAction(act -> {
            sct.process();
        });
        //следующий код приводит к ошибке
        //java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
        /*btn.setOnAction(act -> {
            Service<Void> service = new Service<Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Task<Void> createTask() {
                    return new Task<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        protected Void call() throws Exception {
                            sct.process();
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
            service.start();
        });*/
        /*btn.setOnAction(act -> {
            Task task = new Task<Void>() {
                @Override
                public Void call() throws InterruptedException {
                    final int max = 1000;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
                        if (isCancelled()) {
                            break;
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(5);

                        this.updateMessage(i + "");
                        sct.process();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
        });*/

        root.getChildren().addAll(lbl,btn);



        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему на интерфейс выводится только последняя цифра? как заставить программу выводить информацию постоянно?
Как видно из закомментированного кода второго класса мне подсказывали что нужно создавать потоки, но все попытки приводили либо к ошибке (java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4), либо ни к чему не приводили.

UPD. К сожалению приведенные советы я не смог применить, возможно по причине неопытности, поэтому объявляю конкурс, желательно в ответе выставить уже измененные работающие классы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из вариантов:

```
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class SimpleClassTest extends Task<Void> {

    private final int loops;

    /**
     * Конструктор
     * @param loops количество циклов
     */
    public SimpleClassTest(int loops) {
        this.loops = loops;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            updateMessage(String.format("number - %d", i));
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        return null;
    }

}

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class FXClassTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label lbl = new Label("Test");
        Button btn = new Button("Start");

        SimpleClassTest sct = new SimpleClassTest(25);
        lbl.textProperty().bind(sct.messageProperty());

        btn.setOnAction(act -> {
            new Thread(sct).start();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(lbl,btn), 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

Можно использовать [value](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#valueProperty) вместо [message](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#messageProperty), или `listener` вместо `bind`, или ставить/убирать `bind` в зависимости от [state](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#stateProperty) задачи и т.д.

Comment: Именно то что я искал, хотел бы уточнить - после привязки через "bind" есть ли возможность править метку "вручную" без "unbind", при попытках у меня выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Нет, только с использованием `unbind`. В данном контексте наиболее логичное место для вызова `unbind`: `setOnSucceeded` для `sct`. (Доп. [bindBidirectional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bindBidirectional-javafx.beans.property.Property-))

Answer (score 1):

Все изменения UI нужно проводить в UI потоке (иначе `Not on FX application thread`):

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        label.setText(formatter.format(value));
    }
});
```

Когда вы пытаетесь делать `Thread.sleep` в UI потоке, то ни к чему хорошему это не приходит :)

В целом простой пример счетчика:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int count = 0;
        while(true) {
            count++;

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);

                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        label.setText("" + count);
                    }
                }); 

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю как это использовать, пробовал оба кода, и окружал ими вызов функции в первом классе, и во втором классе, но все равно выдает те же ошибки, либо обновляет счетчик только по завершении цикла, подскажите в какую часть моего кода нужно вставить данную конструкцию чтобы она работала?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то ваша проблема в том, что из другого потока нельзя работать с компонентами JavaFX? Если да, то у меня возникала похожая проблема -  [здесь ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/795641/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-javafx-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC/795723#795723)

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
public void process(){
    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
        Platform.runLater(()->{
            lbl.setText("number - "+i);
        });
        System.out.println("number - "+i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, не могли бы вы подробнее описать, как данный код нужно разместить в моём коде?