# Работа с JavaFX и ее потоком

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

У меня есть JavaFX приложение со своим потоком и еще несколько других потоков.
Мне нужно решить проблему с тем, что из этих потоков нельзя работать с приложением JavaFX. В дополнительном потоке есть бесконечный цикл, при определенных условиях у меня должно создаваться новое окно и показывать или скрывать элементы интерфейса, а цикл должен продолжить свое выполнение. Сейчас использую примерно такой код.

```
new Thread(()->
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(some)
            showNewStageAndChangeDoAnythingWithJavaFX();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Потоки в JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794078/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-javafx)

Comment: @Виктор Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено, оно было очень простым:

```
new Thread(()->
{
    while(true)
    {
        if(some)
            Platform.runLater(() -> showNewStageAndChangeDoAnythingWithJavaFX());
    }
}).start();
```